# Selects dependientes en angularjs no asigna a $scope.municipioSeleccionado

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, angularjs

Estoy atascado con un select dependiente de otro que no está asignando a $scope.municipioSeleccionado. Lo que quiero hacer es que al cargar el primer select (listado de provincias) se rellene el segundo select con los municipios seleccionados para esa provincia. Esta parte la tengo pero no consigo mostrar el valor del municipio seleccionado. Tengo montado el código así:

**index.php**

```
<select ng-model="provinciaSeleccionada" ng-options="provincia.id as provincia.nombre for provincia in listadoProvincias" ng-change="traerMunicipiosProvincia()"></select>

<select ng-model="municipioSeleccionado" ng-options="municipio.nombre for municipio in municipiosAlicante" ng-if="provinciaSeleccionada"></select>
```

**controlador.js**

```
function traerProvincias(){
    return $http.put("includes/php/crud/provincias_municipios.php",{
        accion: 'traerProvincias',
    })
    .then(function (datosDevueltos) {
        $scope.listadoProvincias = _.sortBy(datosDevueltos.data, 'nombre');            
    });
}

function traerMunicipiosProvincia(){

    return $http.put("includes/php/crud/provincias_municipios.php",{
        accion: 'traerMunicipiosProvincia',
        idProvincia: $scope.provinciaSeleccionada
    })
    .then(function (datosDevueltos) {
        $scope.listadoMunicipios = _.sortBy(datosDevueltos.data, 'nombre');

        console.log($scope.listadoMunicipios);
    });
}
```

**llamadas a la BBDD**

```
 function traerProvincias($conn){
        $consulta = 'SELECT pr.id, pr.provincia
        FROM provincias pr';

        $result = $conn->query($consulta);

        while($filaDatos = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $listadoProvincias[] = [
                'id'        => (int)$filaDatos['id'],
                'nombre'    => utf8_encode($filaDatos['provincia'])
            ];
        }

        $conn->close();

        echo json_encode($listadoProvincias);
    }


   function traerMunicipiosProvincia($conn, $idProvincia){
        $consulta = 'SELECT *
                       FROM municipios
                      WHERE provincia_id = '.$idProvincia;

        $result = $conn->query($consulta);

        while($filaDatos = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $listadoMunicipios[] = [
                'id_municipio'  => (int)$filaDatos['id'],
                'nombre'        => utf8_encode($filaDatos['municipio']),
                'longitud'      => (float)$filaDatos['longitud'],
                'latitud'       => (float)$filaDatos['latitud'],
                'id_provincia'  => (int)$filaDatos['provincia_id'],
            ];
        }

        echo json_encode($listadoMunicipios);
    }
```

Las llamadas a la BBDD van bien porque me devuelven datos y los pintan en el desplegable. La cosa es que cuando selecciono un municipio no pinta {{municipioSeleccionado}} en el html y no sé porqué. Imagino que debe ser cosa de los selects.

Comment: donde creas el $scope de municipioSeleccionado? trataste de imprimir en pantalla el valor?

Comment: El $scope de municipioSeleccionado no lo creo en ningún lado, es decir, hago lo mismo con provinciaSelessionada y me lo pinta en el html

Comment: Cuando indicas que no te muestra los municipios seleccionados, te refieres a que no te muestra la lista de municipios o la opción que seleccionas de esa lista?

Comment: La opción de la lista. No me he explicado bien. El listado de municipios lo muestra, pero el seleccionado no lo pinta en el html cuando pincho

Comment: Posiblemente te falte especificar el dato que debe mostrar al momento de seleccionar el item. Cambia tu **ng-options** por esto `municipio.nombre as municipio.nombre for municipio in municipiosAlicante` y nos comentas

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: He subido lo que he hecho aquí: http://franciscogarciavidal.es/fiestas/selects.php

Comment: Mmmm.. creo insistir en que crees una `$scope.municipioSeleccionado` globalmente y pruebes...

Comment: He hecho el cambio y mostrar lo muestra, pero al seleccionar otro municipio de la lista no me municipioSeleccionado del html

Comment: Intenta pasando en el ng-change el ng-modal de la provincia y ya solo lo llamas en tu function. Aunque bueno esa es mi manera de trabajarlo.